# Why is it printing none in my views for the textarea I'm getting from html?

Tags: javascript, html, django-views

In the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="port_param1">Port Parameter 1</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name ="port_param1" id="port_param1" rows="5" onkeyup="copy();"  
     placeholder="e.g. For Access Port mode: 
                       switch access vlan 10
                       For Trunk Port mode:
                       switch trunk native vlan 5
                       switch trunk allow vlan 5, 6">
   </textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

In the view:

```
portpara1 = request.POST.get('port_param1')
print(portpara1)
```

Here I have a textarea within my html for user to type a huge chunk of text. But when I `request.POST.get` of the textarea and printing it, I am receiving the output of `none`. Even when i type just one line of words within the textarea, i still get the output of `none`. So how do i properly get the text keyed in by user on the html to view? And also within the text area, how do i ensure in between rows, the text are seperated with `\n` when i retrieve it to the view but the user keying in the web is just pressing enter for the next row and not typing `\n`. Appreciate if anyone can help !

Updated in html (Added a additional text box):

```
<input type = "text" name = "portpara1" id = "portpara1">
```

Script:

```
function copy()
{
   var port_param1 = document.getElementById("port_param1");
   port_param1.replace(/\r?\n/g, '\n')
   var portpara1 = document.getElementById("portpara1");
   portpara1.value = port_param1.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests work with textareas and inputs with attribute name, not id. So you should add a name attribute and refer to it in your code.

Comment: I got another question, I am able to extract the input to view but I have a issue. So for example, I type the following in the textarea ( First row-123, Second row-234), I will get the same output in my powershell when it is retrieve in my views. How do I change the following to ```123\n234```. Basically ```\n``` before every new line?

Comment: It may be done in different ways, but I think the easiest to come to my mind is with regular expressions. Just add `.replace(/\r?\n/g, '\n')` at the end of your textarea's value, and that should do it. Basically, it replaces every single visible new line to a `\n`. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I managed to did it. But i used this ```replace(/(?:\r|\n|\r\n)/g,'\\n')```

Comment: Well done as well. The first regex worked out for me well. Where I was using it I had a lot of limitations, like no groups in regex and stuff.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for your help :) Really appreciate it as I am currently a beginner in this

Comment: Absolutely. Let me know if you'll need any other questions:)

Comment: Will do, thank you very much :)

Comment: Hi again, I have a question. With my command in the html of ```replace(/(?:\r|\n|\r\n)/g,'\\n')```. I achieve what I want in the html. I retrieve what the same output in django view. But when i convert it to a dict, how come it become ```\\n``` instead of ```\n```?

Comment: It escapes the backslash character probably. In your django try to replace all \\ns with \n.

Comment: What's weird is i used ```request.POST.get``` to put in in a variable in my view. I get something like ```1\n2\n3```. But when i convert to a dict in view, it somehow becomes ```1\\n2\\n3```

Comment: Because it automatically escapes backslash:) It's a safety practice:)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. So it is not a good move to attempt to remove that? Also, is there anyway to remove it?